# How to split the text separated by comma or space and it should not break any word

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a requirement, want to split the text separated by comma or space and it should not break any word in side the div. This div width also changes with respect to device.

Is it possible to do with css

I am using the code.

```
<div class="large-9 medium-10 small-8 columns"><p id="3" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;word-break: break-all; ">Common Situations&nbsp;:&nbsp;access,change,connect,configure,install</p></div>
```

Here the width are represented for the devices as large-9 medium-10 small-8

But same text I am getting in pc as follows

```
Common Situations : access,change,conn
ect,configure,install
```

How can I achieve the above with out breaking any word  w r to different width for div as large-9 medium-10 small-8

Answer (score 1):

There is (currently) no pure CSS way of allowing line breaks after specific characters like commas. You need to insert either the (nonstandard, but working) `<wbr>` tag or the special character U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE after each occurrence a character that should allow a line break after it. The insertion should be handled when generating the HTML document, but if needed, it can be done in client-side JavaScript too:

```html
<div><p id="3" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; width: 12em">Common Situations&nbsp;:&nbsp;access,change,connect,configure,install</p></div>
<script>
var p = document.getElementById('3');
p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, ',\u200b');
</script>
```

I have omitted the class settings (which probably relate to the use of some framework or library), as they are not relevant to the issue. I have set an arbitrary width on the element just to illustrate the wrapping.

Comment: Jukka, that should work nicely. Perhaps you could expand your answer to include a jQuery approach? `$("#3").text(  $("#3").text().replace(/,/g, ',\u200b') )`.

Comment: @Marventus, I know the question was tagged with jquery, but for this specific case, jquery does not have much benefit over plain JavaScript. I suppose the real situation is more complicated (possibly several elements to be handled), and the digit `3` as `id` value, though valid, causes problems in CSS. So the code should be modified to meet the real situation, but I cannot guess how.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 word-break:keep-all;
```

instead of

```
   word-break:break-all;
```

Comment: Hi I applied .but is not effecting. Thanks

Comment: did you apply it inline or in a stylesheet, if in a stylesheet then your inline style will overide it ?

Comment: I added that property as Inline.